# Unable to fetch MySQL data on Ruby on Rails using capybara

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a file called test_spec.rb inside my spec/features folder.
It runs good when I type

```
rake spec
```

But it doesn't load any data from the database. I have put some database in test and development environment in Database.yml

So both database are same, I got only one database, i.e. app_development.

I want that the select query should be able to fetch MySQL data inside the test_spec.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to migrate your database in test environment. 
Try to run this in your Project root folder.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```